# black screen with Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, game-development

I have trouble with Phaser.js. It's a copy of example from phaser.io/examples. And what the hell with it?

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 200, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', {
  preload: preload,
  create: create,
  update: update,
  render: render
});

function preload() {
  game.load.image('arrow', 'img.png');
}

var sprite;

function create() {
  sprite = game.add.sprite(50, 50, 'arrow');
}

function update() {}

function render() {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.15.1/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But all i've got this ->

[Google Drive Link - Screenshot result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nT1zk4tKFm64BnKoe8_2uMfzLzS_6_nk/view?usp=sharing)
or  here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkvR6.png)

Comment: Check that the path to the image is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have set up a Phaser 2 game, while in your html you call the Phaser 3 library.
In Phaser 3 you can start a game like this:

```
var config = {
   type: Phaser.AUTO,
   width: 800,
   height: 600,
   scene: {
     preload: preload,
     create: create,
     update: update,
     render: render
  }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload() {
 this.load.image('arrow', 'img.png');
}

var sprite;

function create() {
  sprite = this.add.image(50,50, 'arrow').setOrigin(0,0);
}

function update() {}

function render(){}
```

https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/index